# Problema envolvendo tabela particionada + Spring Boot: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, spring-boot, spring-jpa

Estou trabalhando com tabelas particionadas usando Postgres e Spring Boot, consegui fazer a partição e nos testes que eu fiz o método GET e POST está funcionando do jeito que eu queria, porém gostaria de ajuda para resolver o seguinte erro, que é retornado quando eu inicio a aplicação:

**GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table teste (data date not null, id int4 not null, nome varchar(255), primary key (data, id))" via JDBC Statement org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table teste (data date not null, id int4 not null, nome varchar(255), primary key (data, id))" via JDBC Statement at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]**

O passo a passo do que eu fiz antes do erro aparecer:

Criei o Model principal, que fará referência a tabela particionada:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "teste")
@IdClass(TesteId.class)
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Teste {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "teste_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "teste_id_seq", sequenceName = "teste_id_seq", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
    private int id;

    @Id
    private LocalDate data;

    private String nome;

}
```

Criei a classe do id composto:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class TesteId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int id;

    private LocalDate data;

}
```

E então iniciei a aplicação, tudo rodou normalmente.

Após isso pausei a aplicação e particionei a tabela 'teste' seguindo a documentação do Postgres: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html Tópico: 5.11.2.1. Example

E minha tabela ficou da seguinte forma:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.teste
(
    data date NOT NULL,
    id integer NOT NULL,
    nome character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT teste_pkey PRIMARY KEY (data, id)
) PARTITION BY RANGE (data);
```

Então eu iniciei a aplicação novamente e o seguinte erro foi impresso no log do Spring Boot:

```
WARN 16668 --- [ main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl : GenerationTarget             
encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table teste (data 
date not null, id int4 not null, nome varchar(255), primary key (data, id))" via JDBC 
Statement org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL 
"create table teste (data date not null, id int4 not null, nome varchar(255), primary 
key (data, id))" via JDBC Statement at 
org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetTo
Database.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final] at 
org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigra
tor.java:562) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final] at 
org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigr
ator.java:507) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
```

Meu application.properties está assim:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/teste
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

Eu sei que alterar o 'spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto' para 'none' resolveria o problema, porém não é a solução que eu desejo, já que não quero gerenciar manualmente todas as alterações no banco de dados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver atualizando o Spring Boot para a última versão e adicionando a seguinte dependência no pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).